# SQL Server Service Broker Queue Conversation Group Id

Tags: sql-server, queue

I create a `UniqueIdentifier` variable `@GroupId` and assign it a value.  I begin `DIALOG WITH RELATED_CONVERSATION_GROUP = @GroupId`.

When I look in the queue, the `conversation_group_id` does not match `@GroupId`. I am trying to send on conversation using a known group conversation Id so I can later `RECEIVE TOP(1) WHERE conversation_group_id = @GroupId`.

Any suggestions? Nothing I try seems to work.

Thanks,

Brandon

Answer (score 0):

In Service Broker, you don't create the conversation handles, it does. When you issue the `begin dialog` statement, think of the @dialog_handle variable as an output variable. If you need to add related conversation later, you'll need to store that value (or otherwise be able to determine) for later use.

Out of curiosity, it seems like you're just getting going with Service Broker. I've been using it for a while and never had a need for "related conversations". What are you trying to do?